# Wordpress - change wp_redirect url to dynamic link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that checks if a user is logged in and then redirects them to a particular static page -

```
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( [153] ) ) {
        wp_redirect('https://my.thinkingmachine.co/vallis');
        exit;
    }
}
```

I want to change it so that instead of going to "https://my.thinkingmachine.co/vallis" they are directed to a dynamic url containing their user name, like this -

```
  $username = $user->user_login;
  return ( '//my.thinkingmachine.co/' . $username . '/' );
```

How do I change the code so that it redirects to this dynamic url instead?

I tried this but it doesn't work -

```
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( [153] ) ) {
        $username = $user->user_login;
      return ( '//my.thinkingmachine.co/' . $username . '/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks

The whole code is -

```
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( [153] ) ) {
        $username = $user->user_login;
        wp_redirect("https://my.thinkingmachine.co/{$username}");
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_not_login_check');
function add_not_login_check()
{
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( [153] ) ) {
        wp_redirect('https://my.thinkingmachine.co/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `return` instead of `wp_redirect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code below:

```
function add_login_check() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( [153] ) ) {
        $username = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
        $url = 'https://my.thinkingmachine.co/'. $username . '/';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

Hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the username is correctly get with this line of code:

```
$username = $user->user_login;
```

You can use this code:

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( [153] ) ) {
        $username = $user->user_login;
        wp_redirect("https://my.thinkingmachine.co/{$username}");
        exit;
    }
}
```

If you want to use a PHP variable inside a string, you have to use double quotes for the string and single braces around the variable.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you think variable interpolation into a double-quoted string will accomplish that the OP's string concatenation version wouldn't.

Comment: I didnt understand your comment, can you explain me pls?

Comment: Sure. Why do you think that `"https://my.thinkingmachine.co/{$username}"` is going to give any different result than `'https://my.thinkingmachine.co/' . $username` does?

Comment: Got it. I know there is no difference, I just wanted to explain the correct way to use the variable interpolation. It happened to me at the start of programming to use single quotes with variable interpolation.

Comment: I understand now. Given that it's good practice to not only provide corrected code, but explain the correction, it seemed like your sentence at the end was explaining why your version would work, when it's actually the correction from `return` to `wp_redirect` that's the true fix.